# How to remove everything before provided value

Tags: regex, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap [Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/) and would like to use a formatter callback to insert html into a column inside the table.  The Bootstrap documentation example formats the link as an anchor link
Ex. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#shirley-partridge

```
    <b-table striped responsive hover :items="episodes" :fields="fields">
           <template v-slot:cell(version)="data">
        <a :href="`${data.value.replace(/[^a-z]+/i,'-').toLowerCase()}`">{{ data.value }}</a>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

I am pulling in a full url from the version property and would like to only use this url in the template, how can I remove everything before my url using the formatter?

```
    this.episodes = response.map((item) => {
          return {
            category: item.fields.title,
            episode_name: item.fields.splash,
            episode_acronym: item.fields.description,
            version: 'https://myurl/webinars' + item.fields.slug + '/' +'test',

          }
        })
```

Desired link would be https://myurl/webinars....

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Preferable a jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you show your `<b-table>` markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working, by keeping the relative url format, and updating the formatter with a - instead of a + sign

```
        <a :href="`${data.value.replace(/[^a-z]-/i,'-').toLowerCase()}`">Definition</a>
```